# When I import ng2-pdf-viewer to ngmodule in my module.ts file, pages of my app not loading

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am using ng2-pdf-viewer on my ionic app. I added like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ShopMenuPage } from './shop-menu.page';
import { PdfComponent } from '../pdf/pdf.component';
import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';
import { QRCodeModule } from 'angularx-qrcode';
import { SharedModule } from '../../shared.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ShopMenuPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    QRCodeModule,
    SharedModule,
    PdfViewerModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ShopMenuPage,
    PdfComponent
  ]
})
export class ShopMenuPageModule {}
```

but when I press ctrl+s to auto compile, pages not load.
But it works when I stop and start the local server.

This is the component I use pdf module:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <ion-button (click)="pdfOpen()">Menüyü Gör</ion-button>
</div>

<pdf-viewer
  scrollX #content
  *ngIf="pdfStatus"
  [src]="pdfSrc"
  [render-text]="true"
  [show-all]="true"
  [original-size]="false"
  style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%"
>

</pdf-viewer>
```

Comment: Do you get an error

Comment: @shadow2020 no I am not getting any errors.